# Would it be considered bad etiquette to self-answer a question summarizing points from other answers and comments?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answering

So I asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44263/what-are-the-requirements-to-use-a-smartgun-system-to-its-full-extent) about a week back and I've received two answers at the current time of posting.

I disagree with with David's answer but asking for clarification and further information in the comments helped me to come to a conclusion about how the rules should be interpreted.

Archaos' answer provides some information in that it corrects an assumption I initially made in my question but it still doesn't fully answer the question and no further update to this answer has been forthcoming after asking about the remaining details.

Having come to a decision myself about what I consider to be the rules-correct answer for this question, would it be considered bad etiquette to self-answer the question based on my further reading and the information in the answers/comments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### No, in fact it's encouraged.

The important things to note when you give your answer:

- Attribution is required. All content on SE is licensed as CC-By-SA and as such the author must be attributed, so if you reuse parts of the other answers, you're required to give them credit for it (plus it's the neighborly thing to do).
- Make sure you put some effort into your answer. It should read like a cohesive answer rather than a summary of two disparate answers and some comments (I've seen people just sort of throw up a comment stream, this isn't what we want here).

Basically, if the current answers didn't quite solve your problem, but some comment discussion did, this is a great opportunity for a well documented, cohesive answer.

Comment: Also, give it some time to collect up votes or down votes before you Mark it correct.

Comment: This also seems like a good time to tick that Community Wiki box.

Comment: @KRyan This is one of the rare situations that truly deserves that box.