# In good subjective questions, should I accept an answer if there are several good ones?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

From other meta I have this quite clear: do not accept an answer if there isn't a good one.

But what should I do when I am requesting experience based advice and there are several good ones, each approaching an angle? What if I can't decide which answer is best because all seems good to me? Should opinion+experience based questions have an accepted answer?

Example: [How to have a game in which one player character is the leader but it's still fun for everyone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38331/how-to-have-a-game-in-which-one-player-character-is-the-leader-but-its-still-fu)

Of my favourite answers, no one seems more correct than the others.

Comment: Mine, of course.

Answer (score 17):

Wait until you use the advice, and then use the checkmark to indicate which one helped you most.

There's no time limit on accepting an answer, so there's no need to rush when the nature of the question requires using the answers before you can know which is best.

(If you find that what works best after all isn't any one answer, but a combination of them or new idea of your own inspired by the experience trying the answers, [it's OK and encouraged to self-answer the question with what actually worked, and accept your own answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4778/would-it-be-considered-bad-etiquette-to-self-answer-a-question-summarizing-point). You can still show appreciation for the other answers with upvotes.)